# What does this regex mean: '[%s]{%d,}' % (chars, min_length)

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

How to parse the following regex:

```
    char = r" -~"
    min_length = 5
   '[%s]{%d,}' % (chars, min_length)
```

Answer (score 5):

That's an [old style format string](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting). The %s and the %d will be replaced with the values of the `chars` and `min_length` variables. The resulting string will be `"[ -~]{5,}"`. `[ -~]` means "A character within the range of space and tilde"*. `{5,}` means "five or more of the preceding value". All together, the pattern means "five or more printable ascii characters".

(*in other words, anything with ordinal value between 32 and 126: `` <space> !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_\`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|} ``.)

Comment: Oops, I forgot that hyphens aren't interpreted literally in character sets. Good eye.